# How do I implement Slicebox? I'm having difficulties

Tags: javascript, jquery, shadowbox

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/09/05/slicebox-3d-image-slider/

I'm trying to implement Slicebox into my website and I'm having issues. I always want to offer users the option of Shadowbox within the same page, so I'm initializing both.

```
        <!-- Shadowbox code. -->
        <link href="javascript/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Shadowbox.init();
        </script>

        <!-- Slicebox Code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.sb-slider').slicebox();
        </script>
```

But I'm not sure how to get it to work within the actual page. I have this linking, as well as these images.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slicebox/js/jquery.slicebox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slicebox/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slicebox/js/jquery.slicebox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slicebox/js/modernizr.custom.13303.js"></script>
```

And

```
            <div class="sb-slider">
                <img src="media/community/thumbnails/abed_annie_troy.jpg" alt="Abed, Annie and Troy" />
                <img src="media/community/thumbnails/season_3.jpg" alt="Intro to season three" />
                <img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_class.jpg" alt="The cast in a classroom" />
            </div>
```

Do I have it in the right directory?

[image: http://imgur.com/FocVx]

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

FULL HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

    <head>

        <!-- This tag is required to make the page valid XHTML. -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

        <!-- Give your page a title. -->
        <title>Photo Gallery for NBC's Community</title>

        <!-- Put your name and a description of the assignment or project here. -->
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="A collection of photos regarding NBC's Community television show." />

        <!-- This links to a sample CSS file. -->
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

        <!-- This include a standard jQuery library and a sample JS file for your own code. -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slicebox/js/jquery.slicebox.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slicebox/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slicebox/js/jquery.slicebox.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/slicebox/js/modernizr.custom.13303.js"></script>

        <!-- Shadowbox code. -->
        <link href="javascript/shadowbox-3.0.3/shadowbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Shadowbox.init();
        </script>

        <!-- Slicebox Code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.sb-slider').slicebox();
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="media/header.png" alt="Community Header" />
            </div>

            <p>Community is an American television comedy series created by Dan Harmon that airs on NBC. The series is about a group of students at a community college in the fictional locale of Greendale, Colorado. The series heavily uses meta-humor and pop culture references, often parodying film and television clichés and tropes. The series premiered Thursday, September 17, 2009, and airs in the 8:00 pm ET time slot. It previously aired in the 9:30 pm ET time slot, beginning with its premiere, but later relocated with its fourth episode. On March 17, 2011, NBC renewed Community for a third season, which premiered on September 22, 2011.</p>

            <div class="sb-slider">
                <img src="media/community/thumbnails/abed_annie_troy.jpg" alt="Abed, Annie and Troy" />
                <img src="media/community/thumbnails/season_3.jpg" alt="Intro to season three" />
                <img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_class.jpg" alt="The cast in a classroom" />
            </div>

            <div id="gallery">
                <table>
                    <tr><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/abed_annie_troy.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Abed, Annie and Troy"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/abed_annie_troy.jpg" alt="Abed, Annie and Troy" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/annie_paintball.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Annie playing paintball"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/annie_paintball.jpg" alt="Annie during the first paintball episode" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/annie.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Annie's Halloween costume"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/annie.jpg" alt="Annie as a skeleton" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/britta_dinosaur.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Jeff's and Britta's Halloween costumes"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/britta_dinosaur.jpg" alt="Britta's and Jeff's Halloween costumes" /></a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_cafeteria.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="In the cafeteria"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_cafeteria.jpg" alt="The cast in the cafeteria" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_class.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="In the classroom"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_class.jpg" alt="The cast in a classroom" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_cloud.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Thinking"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_cloud.jpg" alt="The cast thinking" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_mural.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="In front of a colorful chalkboard"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_mural.jpg" alt="Cast in front of a chalkboard" /></a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast_study_room.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Hanging in the study room"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast_study_room.jpg" alt="The cast in their study room" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/cast.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="In the library"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/cast.jpg" alt="The cast" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/christmas_episode.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Transformed into Christmasy claymation characters"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/christmas_episode.jpg" alt="Claymation Christmas episode" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/pierce.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Pierce hears something!"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/pierce.jpg" alt="Pierce with other students" /></a></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/season_3.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="The introduction to season 3"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/season_3.jpg" alt="Intro to season three" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/show_poster.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="The classic Community poster"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/show_poster.jpg" alt="Poster for the show" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/troy_and_abed.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="Troy and Abed In the Morning!"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/troy_and_abed.jpg" alt="Troy and Abed In The Morning" /></a></td><td><a href="media/community/fullsize/trio_paintball.jpg" rel="shadowbox[Gallery]" title="After an intense paintball match"><img src="media/community/thumbnails/trio_paintball.jpg" alt="Troy, Annie and Abed after paintball" /></a></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can edit your question and post the full HTML source - or even better, upload a demo and post a link?

Comment: I just looked at imgur.com/FocVx, which I assume is where you're trying to do this.  I don't see anything with a class of sb-slider.  Nor do I see the slicebox script.

Comment: @dnuttle: He's just showing his directory structure at this image hosting service.

Comment: @Doug Smith: Where on your page are you calling `$('.sb-slider').slicebox();` It's likely that you're trying to access a DOM element which hasn’t even been loaded at the time of initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to use DOM element when DOM is not ready. Please do following changes. It should work like this.

**First of all, remove these two script tag. They are unnecessary, we just combine them to only one script tag.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Shadowbox.init();
</script>

<!-- Slicebox Code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.sb-slider').slicebox();
</script>
```

**Then just write these lines**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    Shadowbox.init();
    <!-- Slicebox Code -->
    $('.sb-slider').slicebox();
});
</script>
```